# Append JS to not include a % character

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have one JSON value which is writing into HTML and CSS from the following JS:

```
$('#team2-keyPlayer2-rating').css('width', data[team1].keyPlayers.keyPlayer1.rating);
$('#team1-keyPlayer1-rating').html(data[team1].keyPlayers.keyPlayer1.rating);
```

The first command is working great. It's controlling the % of the CSS bar. 
The second command is writing the value to HTML.

IE: "90%"

My issue is I dont want to show the "%" when writing to the HTML. Is there a way to delete the % from writing to the HTML without deleting the % from the JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can use replace

```
data[team1].keyPlayers.keyPlayer1.rating.replace('%', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways. If the value is always of the format X% then you can simply chop off the last character with [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice):

```
.html(data[team1].keyPlayers.keyPlayer1.rating.slice(0, -1));
```